# recordPlot() not showing in plot_grid() in newer versions of R

Tags: r, plot-grid

I was trying to run a code from a year ago that uses `recordPlot()` function and then plots it using `plot_grid()` from the cowplot package. While the code still works on my old computer with R 4.1.1 using RStudio 2021.09.0 it does not work on my fresh install of R 4.3.1 with the newest RStudio 2023.06.1. Apart from my old code the `plot_grid()` does not plot anything from `recordPlot()` anymore.

Here is a simple code that works with the older version. It produces two graphs next to each other.

```
library(cowplot) 

plot(1:5, 1:5)
p1 <- recordPlot()

plot(1:10, 1:10)
p2 <- recordPlot()

plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

However, in the new version it just plots a blank file. Does anybody know where the problem is?

I tried to save the plots in a list and then plot them using `plot_grid(plotlist = p)`. But it still produces blank plot.